# Alteração de Simulated Metrics no Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-8

Com a alteração de Simulated Metrics qual das opções abaixo usar?

[image: print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A inferred é padrão, com ela você poderá utilizar o Storyboard normalmente, porém na parte inferior do Xcode existe a simulação das telas do aparelho através de ícones dos devices.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, actualmente já tenho usado com o sumiço do Size device fiquei meio perdido